# Deny access to information_schema in MariaDB

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-injection, code-injection, information-schema

I am looking for the best way possible to deny users access to information_schema in Maria DB. By default each user has the right to access the information_schema, but can see only the rows in the tables that correspond to objects for which the user has the proper access privileges.

I want to block that too!, to have a better security in place to avoid SQL injection. Please let me know how can we achieve that.

```
revoke select on information_schema.* from mu@localhost;
```

This also does not work as I get access denied error even for the root user.

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'

I am open to any kind of solution which can block the access, either at DB side or firewall side. The main aim is to be more prepared for SQL injection threat.

Comment: How does not having access to information schema prevent an SQL injection threat?

Comment: ah my apologies, let me be more specific. I understand that it will not stop the SQL injection completely but still it can do further damage. I ask it more than anything because there is a method for sql injection in which this same table can be consulted to obtain information about it, make a database mapping. I just want to avoid it. 

I know it will not be a complete solution but still if you could suggest a way then it will be really helpful.

Comment: From what I know of SQL injection, you have to prevent that completely before the SQL reaches the database. At the point a malicious actor reaches the information_schema table, I think the battle is already lost if you're trying to prevent it. It might be preferred to prevent it in some cases but I can't really think of any such cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can't revoke access to INFORMATION_SCHEMA. If a user has access to query the tables, they implicitly have access to query metadata about those tables.

To protect against SQL injection attacks, you should fix vulnerabilities in your client code. For example, use parameterized queries instead of string-concatenation when formatting dynamic SQL queries.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your reply Bill!

Yes, you are right and for this I found the solution by using proxySQL. I tested it, after creating the rules using regular expression and it worked as expected. Below is the link for their official documentation.

https://proxysql.com/

Comment: Blocking access to INFORMATION_SCHEMA means, that the user can't retrieve information about creation_time, Everything else can be retrieved by `SHOW CREATE TABLE` or by checking metadata. And writing filter rules to revoke complete access to information schema is quite complex if not impossible, since you need complex filtering, which doesn't reduce risk of SQL injection.

Comment: I guess any amount of other work is preferable to actually fixing vulnerabilities in your code?